# Counting the number of times words in an array that are within a sentence

Tags: c#

I am writing code that will count the number of times each word in an array appears as well as the total of number of all the words appearing. I have managed to create an array which allows the user to add in a number of words they wish to check. However, I am struggling to find a way to count the number of times each word is within the sentence individually (I can only get it working for the first element of the array).

I have tried a for loop that when completed it will move to the next element in the array but it does not start for loop again for the next element but ends the code block.

```
int occurences = 0;

string[] words = new string[_wordCount];

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type in the censored words you wish to be counted: ");
    words[i] = Console.ReadLine();

    if (_sentence.Contains(words[i]))
    {
        occurences++;
    }

    if (i > words.Length)
    {
        i++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Number of censored word occurences: " + occurences);
return occurences;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to calculate each word occurrence separately like this:

```
int i, j, woccurence, occurences = 0;
string[] words, details = new string[_wordCount];
for (i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type in the censored words you wish to be counted: ");
    words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    woccurence = 0;
    details = _sentence.Split(' ');
    for (j = 0; j < details.Length; j++)
        if (details[j] == words[i])
            woccurences++;
    Console.WriteLine("Number of censored word occurences: " + woccurences);
    occurences += woccurences;
}
Console.WriteLine("Number of total censored words occurences: " + occurences);
return occurences;
```

**Details**

In each cycle of the loop, you count the number of occurrences of a word from the beginning using `woccurence` and print it out, then you add this value to the total `occurrence`.

Comment: Thank you very much this code seems to be working as intended. However, if it is not too much to ask, may you go through how the code works so that I can learn from it and any mistakes I made?

Comment: Check my answer now. Is this enough?

Comment: Yes! Thank you again, appreciate it.

Comment: Now the code can give you the number of occurrences within the sentence.

Comment: Yeah this counts the amount within a sentence thanks. What was the need for details? To make sure it misses out on spaces and punctuation?

Comment: How does the for loop work if you can explain how the first iteration works for example?

Comment: `Split(' ')` removes the spaces and takes only the words, then it puts it into `details` array. After that you can check every word to know if it is a censor word or not.

Comment: Understood, is there an easier way to remove punctuation also or would I have to take the long method of converting to char and using the function IsLetter()?

Comment: I have an idea. You can search for the censor word, and if you find it you get the substring after it, then search again until you no more find it. Hence, you will not bother yourself with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

if sentence consists of words seperated by a space, you can use string.split to make it an array that you can then iterate throguh.

```
var sentenceArray = _sentence.Split(new Char [] {' '});
```

And then loop through sentence array within your main words loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where _sentence or _wordCount are being set, but let me know if this is what you have in mind.

Caveat: I'm assuming here the user will input each word with a single space between words when prompted. You'll probably want to handle the case where user uses too much space, commas, etc.

```
    static int GetWords()
    {
       int occurences = 0;
       int _wordCount = 0;

       string _sentence = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
       string[] words = new string[_sentence.Length];

       Console.WriteLine("Type in the censored words you wish to be counted: ");
       string censoredWordString = Console.ReadLine();
       string[] censoredWords = censoredWordString.Split(' ');

       for (int i = 0; i < censoredWords.Length; i++)
       {                  
           if (_sentence.Contains(censoredWords[i]))
           {
              occurences++;
           }                       
       }

       Console.WriteLine("Number of censored word occurences: " + occurences);

       return occurences;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a dictionary. Specifically with using a `<key, value>` of `string` and `int`.

```
int occurances = 0;
string[] words = new string[_wordCount];
var results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var splitSentence = _sentence.Split(' ').ToArray();


for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type in the censored words you wish to be counted: ");
    words[i] = Console.ReadLine();

    if(_sentence.Contains(words[i]))
    {
        if(!results.ContainsKey(words[i]))
        {
            results.Add(words[i], 0);
        }

        for(var j = 0; j < splitSentence.Length; j++)
        {
            if(splitSentence[j] == words[i])
            {
                 results[words[i]]++;
                 occurances++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a dictionary, the first 'parameter' must be unique, so any time a word reappears you just need to check if that key exists first, it'll just add to the count (the `value` in the `key, value` pair).

Comment: "you'll be iterating by 2" it's not true, just when i is bigger than words.Length, i.e never because the compare inside loop (i < words.Length) will exit before

Comment: A momentary episode of dyslexia I guess. Regardless though, it's unnecessary, and I removed it from the answer.

Comment: How would I be able to count multiple words separately. For example, sentence input is "I have some cheese, cheese is good" and the chosen words are cheese and good. I expect the output to be "cheese: 2, good: 1, total: 3". How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: So, in that instance what you'd have is a dictionary with `cheese` and `good` for the keys, and for the dictionary's values `1` and `3` respectively. So if you want to see how many times a specific word shows up, you only need to do `var someInt = results["cheese"]`. (And replace `"cheese"` with whatever word you're looking for.) Though I would suggest what @terrencep suggested, and break up `_sentence` by spaces. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Drilzone Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int occurences = 0;

string sentence = "This is a test sentence. This sentence is test. This sentence do nothing.";

var sentenceWords = new string(sentence.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray()).Split(' ');

var wordsFound = new Dictionary<string, int>();

Console.WriteLine("Sentence = " + sentence);

while ( true)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
  Console.WriteLine("Type in a censored word you wish to be counted (enter empty to end): ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  if ( input == "" ) break;
  int count = sentenceWords.Count(word => word.ToLower() == input.ToLower());
  if ( count == 0 )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Can't find \"" + input + "\".");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Found " + count + " occurences of \"" + input + "\".");
    if ( !wordsFound.ContainsKey(input) )
      wordsFound.Add(input, count);
    occurences += count;
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine("Number of total censored words occurences: " + occurences);
foreach ( var item in wordsFound)
  Console.WriteLine("     " + item.Key + ": " + item.Value);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that only using LINQ

```
int totalWords = 0;
var sentence = "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened";

sentence.ToLower().Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x=> {
    totalWords += x.Count();
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key}: {x.Count()}");
});

Console.WriteLine($"Total words: {totalWords}");
```

First of all we use `ToLower()` se we can get rid of lower and uppers

Then We split by a space with `.Split(' ')`

Now we group by each word with `GroupBy(x=>x)`

We need to use `ToList()` to cast de `IGrouping<T>` so we can iterate the results with `ForEach`

Finally we print the results getting the `Key` which reffers to the grouped object and use `Count()` to get the quantity of group contains

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From what I can understand would I need to replace the x with the String array words? As I created in my code "String[] words = new string[_wordCount]"?

Comment: Actually you only need to replace the `sentence` variable content with the sentence you want to analyse. The x is part of the lambda expression

Comment: Don't use `ToList().ForEach()` in LINQ.

Comment: I needed ToList() since I can't foreach a IGrouping<T>, what would be the best option to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ and Regular Expressions:

```
var sentence = "now is the time for all good men to come, to the aid of their country.";
var words = new[] { "time", "to" };

var wordsHS = words.ToHashSet();
var wordRE = new Regex(@"\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var wordCounts = wordRE.Matches(sentence).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
                       .Where(w => wordsHS.Contains(w))
                       .GroupBy(w => w)
                       .Select(wg => new { Word = wg.Key, Count = wg.Count() })
                       .ToList();
var total = wordCounts.Sum(wc => wc.Count);
```