# Replacing words input by the user within a sentence and then outputting the sentence but with the censored/replaced words

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am aiming to replace words within an array (input by the user) that appear in a sentence. I want to then output this sentence but with the replace version which would be either ***** or for example censor would become c****r.

```
static void CensorSelectedWords(string _sentence, int _wordCount)
{
    string[] words = new string[_wordCount];
    string[] splitSentence = new string[_wordCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type in the words you wish to be censored: ");
        words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        splitSentence = _sentence.Split(' ', '.', '?', ',', '!');
        for (int j = 0; j < splitSentence.Length; j++)
            if (splitSentence[j] == words[i])
                splitSentence[j] = words[i].Replace(words[i], "*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(splitSentence);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of times words in an array that are within a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961666/counting-the-number-of-times-words-in-an-array-that-are-within-a-sentence)

Comment: I tried that, however I am struggling to get the sentence to output but with the censored words. I replaced words[i] within the if loop to splitSentence[j]. While changing the last line to output _sentence. However it does not replace the words

Answer (score 0):

You can replace every word within `_sentence` like this:

```
static void CensorSelectedWords(string _sentence, int _wordCount)
{
    string astr;
    string[] words = new string[_wordCount];
    string[] splitSentence = new string[_wordCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type in the words you wish to be censored: ");
        words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        astr = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < words[I].Length; j++)
            astr += "*";
        _sentence = _sentence.Replace(word[i], astr);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(_sentence); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried to modify this so it replaces the word with the right amount of asteriks. I would not need to include split sentence for this would I?

Comment: I edited it to add with the correct number of asterisk. Yes, you don't have to use split, I think you may face a problem in lower case and upper case difference.

Comment: I figured it out. I created a new string called censored then I replaced this string to * that is the same length as the current element in the words array. I then put your method in of replacing everything in the sentence with the new string "censored"

Comment: Can also do it like      
string censored = "";      
_sentence = _sentence.Replace(censored.PadLeft(words[i].Length, '*'));

Comment: @EricWarburton I think you are missing something, it will not give the required result.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef Oh, you are right, I was misusing Replace. It would be _sentence = _sentence.Replace(words[i], censored.PadLeft(words[i].Length, '*'));

Comment: @EricWarburton I think you should say that `censored` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused at what the output should be, but here's one way to do it. I've extracted the functionality of replacing a word with censored text into separate function so it can be modified independently.

The rest is very simple - get a sentence, get a list of censored words, then replace all the words with their censored counterparts in the sentence and display it:

```
public static string HideAllButFirstAndLast(string word)
{
    if (word == null) return null;
    if (word.Length < 4) return new string('*', word.Length);
    return word[0] + new string('*', word.Length - 2) + word[word.Length - 1];
}

private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence: ");
    var sentence = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a comma-separated list of censored words:");
    var censoredWords = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(word => word.Trim())
        .ToList();

    // Split sentence into words, replace words as needed, and join the words again
    sentence = string.Join(" ", sentence.Split().Select(word =>
        censoredWords.Contains(word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            ? HideAllButFirstAndLast(word)
            : word));

    Console.WriteLine(sentence);

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: image of console output]